# Explanation of merge function

Tags: merge, binary-search-tree, pseudocode

I saw some pseudocode in some old exam and I can't really figure out what it's doing.

Can anyone explain it to me?

A and B are BST's.

```
Foo(A,B)
   if A= NULL
     return B
   if B != NULL
      if value[A] > value[B]
           return Foo(B,A)
      left[B] <- Foo(right[A],left[B])
      right[A] <- B
   return A
```

Comment: Where did you see this?

Comment: its just from some exam in my college. i try to figure out hat this doing , and im not sure what to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a binary search tree merge routine. If either `A` or `B` is null (representing an empty tree), it returns the other. Otherwise, it makes sure that the root of `A` is less than the root of `B`; if the roots are in the wrong order, it recurses with the arguments swapped. Then, it recursively merges the right subtree of `A` and the left subtree of `B`, and attaches the result as the left subtree of `B`. Finally, it attaches `B` as the new right subtree of `A` and returns `A`.